# WPF Trying to save color but when i run again application it's always white

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I'm trying to give user a possibility to change color of the application. I'm using WPF Extended Toolkit to get Color and then save it into Settings so when I run again it, color will be applied. The problem is that for Rectangle it works perfectly but for Label and it background, when I run application again it turns automaticly white instead to saved Color. Here's my code:

Options class and xaml

```
public Options(MainWindow main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        window = main;

        BackgroundColor.SelectedColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Settings.Default.Main_Background);
        TopBarBackColor.SelectedColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Settings.Default.Main_TopBack);
    }

    private void Color_SelectedColorChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Color> e)
    {
        Settings.Default.Main_Background = BackgroundColor.HexadecimalString;
        Settings.Default.Main_TopBack = TopBarBackColor.HexadecimalString;
        Settings.Default.Save();
        window.ColorChange(Settings.Default.Main_Background, Settings.Default.Main_TopBack);

    }
```

MainWindow where I have label(TopBarMain) and rectangle(Background)

```
public void ColorChange(String _Main_B, String _Main_TopBar)
    {
        var converter = new BrushConverter();

        try
        {
            Background.Fill = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(_Main_B);
            TopBarMain.Background = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(_Main_TopBar);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            Background.Fill = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#E5EEEEEE");
            TopBarMain.Background = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#7FC3C3C3");
        }


    }
```

And I call it like this then running an application:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ColorChange(Settings.Default.Main_Background, Settings.Default.Main_TopBack);

        option = new Options(this);

    }
```

Where option is:

> Options option;

To call Options class.
I have no clue anymore where is the problem. Please help.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint at ColorChange in MainWindow, what are the values of Main_Background and Main_TopBack?

Comment: You mean when I load colors? In MainWindow()?

Comment: Also does Color_SelectedColorChanged ever get called?

Comment: Yes it's an event from Extended WPF Toolkit in Color Canvas. It runs when color is changed. The color of "Background" is always stored correctly and always works as it should. Only Label color is never saved but it changes when I use Color Canvas.

Comment: So in MainWindow, when you load the colors, does Settings.Default hold the right colors?

Comment: Main_Background does, I'm not sure about Main_TopBack. It's same as Main_Background but I have no clue. How can I check this?

Comment: Really noone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did it. The problem was that when Component were initialized, I was changing Selected Color of Color Canvas, then the Selected Color event was running automatically and it was changing mine Settings Main_TopBack variable to default (white) and saving it. All I did I just implemented boolean control if colors were loaded like this:

```
bool ColorsLoaded = false;
    public Options(MainWindow main)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        window = main;

        BackgroundColor.SelectedColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Settings.Default.Main_Background);
        TopBarBackColor.SelectedColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Settings.Default.Main_TopBack);

        ColorsLoaded = true;
    }

    private void Color_SelectedColorChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Color> e)
    {
        if (ColorsLoaded)
        {
            Settings.Default.Main_Background = BackgroundColor.HexadecimalString;
            Settings.Default.Main_TopBack = TopBarBackColor.HexadecimalString;
            Settings.Default.Save();
            window.ColorChange();
        }

    }
```

However thanks for help.